# Work with multiple checkboxes in the edit form in React and react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying 4 checkboxes (`this.state.people`). Loads two checkboxes (`this.state.peopleChecked`) into the edit form that are already checked. The problem is that these two checkboxes are marked all the time, they cannot be unchecked. If I check one checkbox then one object (its id) goes to the `selectPeopleId` array, if two then two (id) goes to the array.

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hwabiy?file=index.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      people: [
        {
          'firstname': "Paul",
          'id': "1"
        },
         {
          'firstname': "Martin",
          'id': "2"
        },
         {
          'firstname': "Joseph",
          'id': "3"
        },
         {
          'firstname': "Gregor",
          'id': "4"
        }
      ],
       peopleChecked: [
         {
          'firstname': "Martin",
          'id': "2"
        },
         {
          'firstname': "Gregor",
          'id': "4"
        }
      ],
      selectPeopleId: []
    }
  }



  handleSelect = (person) => {
    const newArray = this.state.peopleChecked.filter(item => item.id !== person.id);

    this.setState({
      selectPeopleId: person.id,
      peopleChecked: newArray
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.people.map(person => (
          <div key={person.id} className="mb-1">
            <Form.Check 
              type={'checkbox'}
              id={person.id}
              label={person.firstname}
              checked={this.state.peopleChecked.some(({ id}) => id === person.id)}
              onChange = {() => this.handleSelect(person)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you removing people from your `peopleChecked` array when unchecking a box ?

Comment: You want to uncheck the pre selected checkbox or not?

Comment: @Treycos I updated my code. I deleted in `function handleSelect()` in `const newArray = this.state.peopleChecked.filter(item => item.id !== person.id);` but it doesn't work

Comment: Do not change code from an original question. Answers and comments made before that change may now lose context, be confusing, or just be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this,

```
selectPeopleId: person.id,
```

Every time the checkbox status changes, your `selectPeopleId` will have only latest `id` which is last one clicked.

You can do this,

```
handleSelect = (person) => {

  //Check if clicked checkbox is already selected
  var found = this.state.peopleChecked.find((element) => {
    return element.id == person.id;
  });

  if(found){
    //If clicked checkbox already selected then remove that from peopleChecked array
    this.setState({
      peopleChecked: this.state.peopleChecked.filter(element => element.id !== person.id),
      selectPeopleId: this.state.selectPeopleId.filter(element => element !== person.id)
    }, () => console.log(this.state.peopleChecked))
  }else{
    //If clicked checkbox is not already selected then add that in peopleChecked array
    this.setState({
      selectPeopleId: [...this.state.selectPeopleId, person.id],
      peopleChecked: [...this.state.peopleChecked,person]
    }, () => console.log(this.state.selectPeopleId))
  }
}
```

**Note:** You won't get `id`'s for pre-selected (from `peopleChecked` array) checkboxes in `selectPeopleId` array. Because initially 2 checkboxes are selected, when you select another checbox your `selectPeopleId` array contains only 1 value, but `peopleChecked` array contains 3 object's (2 initially selected).

You can avoid `selectPeopleId` array and just use `peopleChecked` array.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pmc2vz) (Using simple input)

Comment: OP, would app functionality allow for the entire "people checked" state be completely re-calculated on every (un)check? That could significantly simplify code. For every (un)click flush the peopleChecked array, iterate the entire checkbox set simply adding all checked. No "if / else" logic needed, Array searches are eliminated.  I've seen this technique several times and never with any noticable performance hit.